# Resizing GTK Widgets into vbox in C

Tags: c, gtk

Well, I'm having a problem with a small interface that i'm doing in GTK.

I have some widgets into a box, exactly three widgets, and I put them into a vbox with `gtk_box_pack_start`.
I resized these widgets with `gtk_widget_set_size_request` function, but seems don't take effect because widgets are expanded to the total width of the vbox, and don't respect the size that I fixed in a function.

The piece of code that make this is:

```
enter = gtk_button_new();
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(enter), gtk_image_new_from_file("iconos/submit.png"));
gtk_widget_set_size_request(enter, 195, 32);

//User,pass
login->user = gtk_entry_new();
login->passwd = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_widget_set_size_request(login->user, 195, 32);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(login->passwd, 195, 32);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(v_box), login->user, FALSE, FALSE, 10);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(v_box), login->passwd, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(v_box), enter, FALSE, FALSE, 10);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), v_box);
```

If I put these widgets into an alignment, I have no problem, the size is fixed right.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to achieve by setting the size? As the documentation for `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` says,

> Note the inherent danger of setting any fixed size - themes, translations into other languages, different fonts, and user action can all change the appropriate size for a given widget. So, it's basically impossible to hardcode a size that will always be correct.

You can set the size *request* of a widget, but that's not the same as setting the *size*; we can't always get what we want, and so in certain circumstances the widget doesn't get the size it requests. This is one of those cases.

GTK is designed so that you shouldn't really have to set fixed sizes for widgets. (See the above quote from the documentation.) There's usually a better way to achieve what you want.

In this case, put your button in a `GtkHButtonBox` with `gtk_container_add`, and pack the button box into your vertical box, with the `expand` and `fill` parameters set to `FALSE`, as you were doing before.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my retard answer. Basically, if a widget is into a gtk_alignment, i can resize this widget in a size that i want, but if it is out of gtk_alignment, for example into a vertical_box, gtk_widget_set_size_request doesn't take any effect.

I don't known if I explain this correctly, sorry.

Comment: @Leber, I didn't mean what are you literally trying to do with the widget's container and size request - I got that from your original question. I'm asking what part of your design requires you to set a hardcoded size. GTK is designed in such a way that it's usually not necessary to hardcode the size of a widget, which is why the VBox can override the size request. So if you say what effect you're trying to create, people at StackOverflow can help you do that. We certainly don't think you're a retard.

Comment: How are you. I will try to explain this better. I have a button into a VBox, and i want that this button has a specific size, for example 150x50. I trying with gtk_widget_set_size_request but this doesn't work. Maybe i don't understand the funcionality of this function. Sorry for my english. If you need more details, ask me. Thanks

Comment: @Leber, my question is _why_ do you want the button to have a specific size of 150x50. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Hi, simply is an aesthetic reason. I don't want that the buttonfill all width of the vbox. Is it a wrong decision?

Comment: @Leber, you can use a "button box" to do that. See the edited answer.

Comment: @ptomato, thanks a lot. I tried it and it works fine. If i could vote you, i'll do.

Comment: What you can do at any amount of reputation is to click the checkmark next to the answer. This lets people know that you have accepted the answer as the correct one, and gives you 2 reputation points.